# Calculate timestamp duration using UNIX timestamps

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, timestamp, duration

I want to calculate the duration within groups of the same `subs_no`, and `year`.

Note, This is slightly different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74038285/calculate-duration-within-groups-in-pyspark) because the column `new_ts` is UNIX timestamp, not string.

Here's my code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df_subs_loc_movmnt_ts = df_subs_loc_movmnt.withColumn("new_ts",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("ts"),"HH:mm:ss"),"HH:mm:ss"))
w = W.partitionBy('subs_no', 'year').orderBy('new_ts')
df_subs_loc_movmnt_duration = df_subs_loc_movmnt_ts.withColumn('duration', F.regexp_extract('new_ts' - F.min('new_ts').over(w),"HH:mm:ss", 0))
```

but the `df_subs_loc_movmnt_duration` is always null

```
+--------+---------------+--------+---------------+-------------+----+-----+---+--------+--------+
| date_id|             ts| subs_no|            cgi|       msisdn|year|month|day|  new_ts|duration|
+--------+---------------+--------+---------------+-------------+----+-----+---+--------+--------+
|20200801|17:00:10.000000|10100559|510-11-610104-9|3729882521647|2022|    6|  1|17:00:10|    null|
|20200801|17:09:39.000000|10100559|510-11-610104-9|3729882521647|2022|    6|  1|17:09:39|    null|
|20200801|06:44:55.000000|10100559|510-11-610034-6|3729882521647|2022|    6|  1|06:44:55|    null|
|20200801|17:45:35.000000|10100559|510-11-610079-5|3729882521647|2022|    6|  1|17:45:35|    null|
|20200801|17:48:05.000000|10100559|510-11-610660-4|3729882521647|2022|    6|  1|17:48:05|    null|
|20200801|18:07:25.000000|10100559|510-11-610127-6|3729882521647|2022|    6|  1|18:07:25|    null|
+--------+---------------+--------+---------------+-------------+----+-----+---+--------+--------+
```

Comment: your `new_ts` column must be a string, how do you intend to subtract 2 strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `from_unixtime` in the first line, use it below, because this function will convert your timestamp into string, but later you do a calculation which requires a timestamp/long format (not a string). Also, you don't need `regex_extract` when you use `from_unixtime` with "HH:mm:ss" format.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df_subs_loc_movmnt = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('17:00:10.000000', '10100559', 2022, '17:00:10'),
     ('17:09:39.000000', '10100559', 2022, '17:09:39'),
     ('06:44:55.000000', '10100559', 2022, '06:44:55'),
     ('17:45:35.000000', '10100559', 2022, '17:45:35'),
     ('17:48:05.000000', '10100559', 2022, '17:48:05'),
     ('18:07:25.000000', '10100559', 2022, '18:07:25')],
    ['ts', 'subs_no', 'year', 'new_ts'])
```

Script:

```py
df_subs_loc_movmnt_ts = df_subs_loc_movmnt.withColumn("new_ts", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("ts"), "HH:mm:ss"))
w = W.partitionBy('subs_no', 'year').orderBy('new_ts')
df_subs_loc_movmnt_duration = df_subs_loc_movmnt_ts.withColumn('duration', F.from_unixtime(F.col('new_ts') - F.min('new_ts').over(w), "HH:mm:ss"))

df_subs_loc_movmnt_duration.show()
# +---------------+--------+----+------+--------+
# |             ts| subs_no|year|new_ts|duration|
# +---------------+--------+----+------+--------+
# |06:44:55.000000|10100559|2022| 24295|00:00:00|
# |17:00:10.000000|10100559|2022| 61210|10:15:15|
# |17:09:39.000000|10100559|2022| 61779|10:24:44|
# |17:45:35.000000|10100559|2022| 63935|11:00:40|
# |17:48:05.000000|10100559|2022| 64085|11:03:10|
# |18:07:25.000000|10100559|2022| 65245|11:22:30|
# +---------------+--------+----+------+--------+
```